# Error https connection between EC2 aws instances. Error: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: node.js, http, ssl, amazon-ec2, https

I have two EC2 instances, one with a WEB application and another with a Node JS application. The web application needs to authenticate with Google Earth Engine by making a request to the Node JS application on the other instance.
But when I try to access via https an error is displayed: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

I already added an elastic IP. I have both instances within the same security group.
Testing the local web application directing to EC2 with Node JS via HTTP I get success.

Answer (score 0):

Several reasons may cause the error, but it typically occurs when there is a mismatch or issue with the SSL configuration.

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55409311/https-raises-err-ssl-protocol-error-for-aws-ec2-ubuntu-instance), you can’t deploy a public ACM certificate directly to an instance. It needs to be applied to a service that supports ACM like an ELB, API Gateway, or a CloudFront distribution, which can be used to offload SSL processing.